# Return value not as expected. AVR C calculation

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr

I am trying to perform the following calculation using an ATmega328P MCU.

= 1000 · 0 + 2000 · 1 + ⋯ + 8000 · 7 / 0+1+⋯+7

In the main routine (as shown here):

```
int main(void)
{
    //variables
    uint16_t raw_values[8];
    uint16_t position = 0;
    uint16_t positions[8];
    char raw[] = " raw";
    char space[] = ", ";
    char channelString[] = "Channel#: ";
    char positionString[] = "Position: ";

    //initialize ADC (Analog)
    initADC();

    //initialize UART
    initUART(BAUD, DOUBLE_SPEED);

    //give time for ADC to perform & finish 1st conversion
    //8us x 25 = 200us
    delay_us(200);

    while(1)
    {
        //get the raw values from the ADC for each channel
        for(uint8_t channel = 0; channel < 8; channel++)
        {
            raw_values[channel] = analog(channel);

            //invert the raw value
            raw_values[channel] = DIVISOR - raw_values[channel];
        }

        for(uint8_t channel = 0; channel < 8; channel++)
        {
            //print the channel#
            transmitString(channelString);
            printDec16bit(channel);
            transmitString(space);

            //print the raw value from the ADC conversion
            printDec16bit(raw_values[channel]);
            transmitString(raw);
            transmitString(space);

            //calculate the position value at each sensor
            transmitString(positionString);
            positions[channel] = (uint16_t)((POSITION_REF/DIVISOR) * raw_values[channel]);
            printDec16bit(positions[channel]);
            printCR();
        }

        printCR();

        //calculate and display 'position'
        position = calculatePosition(positions);
        printDec16bit(position);
        printCR();
        printCR();


        //add a delay
        delay_ms(2000);
    }
}
```

I am calling the following function, but the return value I am getting is way off.

```
uint16_t calculatePosition(uint16_t* channel_positions)
{
    uint32_t intermediates[8];
    uint32_t temp_sum = 0;
    uint16_t divisor = 0;
    uint16_t value = 0;

    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        intermediates[i] = channel_positions[i] * ((i + 1) * 1000);
    }

    for(uint8_t j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        temp_sum = temp_sum + intermediates[j];
    }

    for(uint8_t k = 0; k < 8; k++)
    {
        divisor = divisor + channel_positions[k];
    }

    value = temp_sum/divisor;

    return value;
}
```

Alternatively, I have even tried this code, and get a result that is not what I expect.

```
uint16_t calculatePosition(uint16_t* channel_positions)
{
    uint16_t position;
    position = ((1000 * channel_positions[0]) + 
                (2000 * channel_positions[1]) + 
                (3000 * channel_positions[2]) + 
                (4000 * channel_positions[3]) + 
                (5000 * channel_positions[4]) + 
                (6000 * channel_positions[5]) + 
                (7000 * channel_positions[6]) + 
                (8000 * channel_positions[7])) /
                (channel_positions[0] + 
                 channel_positions[1] + 
                 channel_positions[2] + 
                 channel_positions[3] + 
                 channel_positions[4] + 
                 channel_positions[5] + 
                 channel_positions[6] + 
                 channel_positions[7]);
    return position;
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?  For an array of values such as {15, 12, 5, 16, 11, 35, 964, 76} I expect a result of 6504, but instead I get a value in the 200's (or some other weird value).

Comment: Please create a [mre] with a minimal main function demonstrating what's wrong. Show actual and expected output. Also, I think you should explain your formula a bit better.

Comment: Same program as shown in my other question, but I narrowed the issue down.  I will delete my other question, and edit this one to show context.

Comment: How do you represent `964 * 7000` as an `uint16_t`? Hint: your calculations overflow.

Comment: I've edited my question, and eliminated the alternative way I did the calculation.

Comment: A [mre] does not mean the main function you are using. It means a *minimal* main function that is enough to demonstrate the problem, which means that WE should be able to just copy the code in the question and compile it and get the same problem you have.

Comment: Also, please be very careful with modifying the question too much when people have started answering. Otherwise you might invalidate existing answers. I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: ok, thx for the feedback.  I've had enough looking at this for one day,  do you want the entire file?  Shall i edit my question and add it so you can copy/paste?

Comment: I have studied the question and answered it. This time a MRE (minimal, reproducible example) was not necessary since I was able to spot the error anyway. But in general, a MRE is a superb tool for debugging code, and it's very often people post questions here where the error isn't in the code they have posted but somewhere else. That is why we are requesting an MRE almost instantly when people post a question. And no, it does not mean the entire file. It means just enough, but no more than necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @mike I updated my answer to also give a demonstration about how to produce a MRE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your input array: `{15, 12, 5, 16, 11, 35, 964, 76}`

Specifically, look at the element that is 964. That element times 7000 is 6748000 which is greater than a `uint16_t` can handle.

There are a number of solutions. One of them is changing to `uint32_t`. If this is not an option, you could extract a factor of 1000, like this:

```
position = 1000 *(
            ((1 * channel_positions[0]) + 
            (2 * channel_positions[1]) + 
            (3 * channel_positions[2]) + 
            (4 * channel_positions[3]) + 
            (5 * channel_positions[4]) + 
            (6 * channel_positions[5]) + 
            (7 * channel_positions[6]) + 
            (8 * channel_positions[7])) /
            (channel_positions[0] + 
             channel_positions[1] + 
             channel_positions[2] + 
             channel_positions[3] + 
             channel_positions[4] + 
             channel_positions[5] + 
             channel_positions[6] + 
             channel_positions[7]));
```

Note that this will not eliminate the problem, but it could possibly reduce it so that the problem never occurs for reasonable input.

Taking the same idea to the loop version, we get:

```
uint16_t calculatePosition(uint16_t* channel_positions)
{
    uint16_t temp_sum = 0;
    uint16_t divisor = 0;

    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        temp_sum  += (channel_positions[i] * (i+1));
        divisor += channel_positions[i];
    }

    return 1000*(temp_sum/divisor);
}
```

Note that you will lose some accuracy in the process due to rounding with integer division. Since you have been very careful with specifying the width, I assume you're not willing to change the type of the input array. This code should give you maximum accuracy with minimal extra memory usage. But if you're running this function often on a 16-bit machine it can impact performance quite a bit.

```
uint16_t calculatePosition(uint16_t* channel_positions)
{
    // Use 32 bit for these
    uint32_t temp_sum = 0;
    uint32_t divisor = 0;

    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        // Copy the value to a 32 bit number
        uint32_t temp_pos = channel_positions[i];
        temp_sum  += temp_pos * (i+1);
        divisor += temp_pos;
    }

    // Moved parenthesis for better accuracy
    return (1000*temp_sum) / divisor;
}
```

Provided that the result can fit in a `uint16_t` there is absolutely zero chance that this version will fail, because the biggest possible value for `1000*temp_sum` is `2,359,260,000` and the biggest value it can hold is `4,294,967,295`.

### Sidenote about MRE (minimal, reproducible example)

MRE:s are described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

In this example, a good main function to post in the question would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{ 
    uint16_t positions[] = {15, 12, 5, 16, 11, 35, 964, 76}; 
    uint16_t pos = calculatePosition(positions); 
    printf("%d\n", pos); 
}
```

It's enough to demonstrate the problem you had and no more.

Answer (score 0):

As it was said, the problem is in integer overflow.

Be careful when moving the multiplier outside, when using integer math! `(A * 1000) / B` does not equal to `(A / B) * 1000`.

The simplest solution, to convert first of operands in each operation into a wider type. Others will be converted implicitly. E.q.

```
    ...
    position = ((1000UL * channel_positions[0]) + 
                (2000UL * channel_positions[1]) + 
                (3000UL * channel_positions[2]) + 
                (4000UL * channel_positions[3]) + 
                (5000UL * channel_positions[4]) + 
                (6000UL * channel_positions[5]) + 
                (7000UL * channel_positions[6]) + 
                (8000UL * channel_positions[7])) /
                ((uint32_t)channel_positions[0] + 
                 channel_positions[1] + // no need to convert, it will be converted implicitly
                 channel_positions[2] + // since previous operand is wider
                 channel_positions[3] + 
                 channel_positions[4] + 
                 channel_positions[5] + 
                 channel_positions[6] + 
                 channel_positions[7]);
```

Comment: Is the result variable 'position' in this example of type  uint16_t.... Knowing the result will always be an integer?

Comment: yes, integer divided by integer gives integer result

Comment: Minor detail, but technically it is not overflow. Only signed integers overflow, and the behavior of this is undefined. But here it is unsigned integers.

Comment: While [C89 claims "computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.1.2.5), this is C specific language; the modular arithmetic is defined (wraps around), but none the less does [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), as the true sum does not fit. It just can't produce the exception (and in this case would still overflow unless the type of `posititon` is also changed).